# Unable to display alert

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, scriptmanager, clientscript

Actually,I tried showing an alert using `ClientScript`,But it is not showing .

My code :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('File Downloaded at Location C:\\VOWF-Downloads\\');", false);
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "MsgBox", "File Downloaded at Location C:\\VOWF-Downloads\\", true);
```

Both the codes are not working :(

Comment: where did you put this code? Assuming you are talking about Asp.Net in which event?

Comment: grid_CustomButtonCallback of Devexpress GridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible to use RegisterStartupScript when devexpress controls execute callbacks.

[a possible workaround](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q215238)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:-

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanel, updatePanel.GetType(), "a_key", "<script type='text/javascript' src='yourfile.js'></script>", false);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanel, updatePanel.GetType(), "a_key", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('file downloaded');</script>", false);
```

Also in the first line where you are using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript, include script flag is set to false which I feel should be true in your case.